# Studying for a single term of a course that lasts longer than 6 months in all (but one semester is less than 6mo)

Tags: united-kingdom, study

Is it legal for a US citizen on a 6m visitor's leave to study on a course that is more than 6 months in total for a semester that is less than 6 months?

A student visa is not required to take a course of study that is less than 6 months.

What if a course is more than 6 months but one would like only to take a single term of it before converting their visa. Is this permitted?

Comment: Would taking the course be the main purpose of the visit?

Comment: Everything depends on the answer to @PatriciaShanahan's question. You can edit this for clarity and we can reopen it then.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

“**Study**

25 Visitors may carry out the following study:

(a) educational exchanges or visits with a state funded school or academy or independent school; or

(b) a maximum of 30 days study on:

(i) recreational courses (not English language training);

(ii) a short-course (which includes English language training) at an accredited institution;

provided that the main purpose of the visit is not to study and the study is not at a state funded school or academy.“

Note: There is no mechanism to convert from visitor status to a study visa from within the UK.

Comment: How do I know if an academy or school is state funded or not?

Comment: @Joseph P. They will be classed as ‘private’ or ‘independent’ https://www.gov.uk/types-of-school You can search using this tool https://www.compare-school-performance.service.gov.uk/?_ga=2.48550246.1118377410.1600102894-1287242294.1599671260

Comment: Does that include sixth form institutions? I can't find mine.

Comment: @Joseph P. Sixth form institutions are probably state-funded https://www.gov.uk/guidance/16-to-19-funding-how-it-works Have you asked yours? Or checked its website?

Comment: What is the main purpose of the visit?